# Android: NotificationListenerService wasn't created again

Tags: android, notifications

After the app crashed because of some bugs for the first time, the NLService was created and bound again, but after 2nd time or 3rd time..., the NLService wasn't created and bound any more, even the checkbox in

`Settings > Security > Notification access`

is checked, how can I do with this situation?

NLService:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
import android.util.Log;

public class NLService extends NotificationListenerService {
  private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "==onCreate==");
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "==onDestroy==");
  }

  @Override
  public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Log.i(TAG, "**********  onNotificationPosted");
    Log.i(TAG, "ID :"
        + sbn.getId()
        + "\t"
        + sbn.getNotification().tickerText
        + "\t"
        + sbn.getPackageName());
  }

  @Override
  public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Log.i(TAG, "********** onNOtificationRemoved");
    Log.i(TAG, "ID :"
        + sbn.getId()
        + "\t"
        + sbn.getNotification().tickerText
        + "\t"
        + sbn.getPackageName());
  }

  @Override public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    Log.d(TAG, "==onStartCommand==");
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
  }

  @Override public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "==onBind==");
    return super.onBind(intent);
  }

  @Override public void onRebind(Intent intent) {
    super.onRebind(intent);
    Log.d(TAG, "==onRebind==");
  }

  @Override public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "==onUnbind==");
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
  }
}
```

and registered in manifest.xml

```
<service android:name="com.kpbird.nlsexample.NLService"
         android:label="@string/app_name"
         android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Could you give me some comments or advices please if you think this is not a problem?

Answer (score 2):

Still got the problem?

I am in the same situation and this NLService seems won't to be collaborative...

As a **"fake" workaround** I have notice that if you check and uncheck the `Settings > Security > Notification access` during a debug session and put a breakpoint in the onCreate() you can intercept when the service starts but is not so clear why sometimes stops...

Another possibility is to reboot the device...

try maybe you'll find a way to solve, I'm still trying...

**UPDATE**

Maybe something is changed in the service.
This is my test that is working on multiple devices (I've try it for days).

After install the app you can enabling the notification access in settings and than you can try the code.

**build.gradle** file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
       applicationId "your_application_id"
       minSdkVersion 18
       targetSdkVersion 23
       versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
}
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** file 
Here we declare and add the service with NotificationListener (name of the class that we create)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="insert_your_package">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".AMain"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".NotificationListener"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**AMain.java** file

```
package insert_your_package;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AMain extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected TextView textView;
    protected NotificationReceiver notificationReceiver;

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

        notificationReceiver = new NotificationReceiver();

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("com.dev.name.test");

        registerReceiver(notificationReceiver, intentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String temp = intent.getStringExtra("notification_event") + "\n" + textView.getText();

            textView.setText(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

**NotificationListener.java** file

```
package insert_your_package;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService;
import android.service.notification.StatusBarNotification;
import android.util.Log;

public class NotificationListener extends NotificationListenerService {

    private String TAG = this.getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

        Log.i(TAG, "**********  onNotificationPosted");
        Log.i(TAG, "ID :" + sbn.getId() + "\t" + sbn.getNotification().tickerText + "\t" + sbn.getPackageName());

        Intent i = new Intent("com.dev.name.test");
        i.putExtra("notification_event", sbn.getPackageName() + " posted");

        sendBroadcast(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {

        Log.i(TAG, "**********  onNotificationPosted");
        Log.i(TAG, "ID :" + sbn.getId() + "\t" + sbn.getNotification().tickerText + "\t" + sbn.getPackageName());

        Intent i = new Intent("com.dev.name.test");
        i.putExtra("notification_event", sbn.getPackageName() + " removed");

        sendBroadcast(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

as you can see the text add every notification **posted** or **removed** that happens. Now that the service is working properly we can make what we want.

[image]

Try and tell if it works.

Comment: Yep, still confused about this problem. My compromise solution is to record notification access status and then remind user to recheck the permission

Comment: I think it's a bug of android api. Anyway, thanks for your answer and comments. Please tell me if you find any better solutions, and so do I.

Comment: Maybe, or probably some other service takes the priority and than our loses the function. If I'll find a solution I'll post here. Good work! And good searching

Comment: Did you guys found any solution for this ?

Comment: Onestly i have put in stop this function...sorry but no news...but if I found a solution I'll share it!